# Flutterflow firebase and custom function

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutterflow

can someone help me i'm new to flutter, i want to get the sum of all the COST variable and that has a marked "RENTED", in firebase and show the result in a TEXT WIDGET

example:

[in firebase]
name: unit1
payment: 1000
Status: Rented

---

name: unit2
payment: 2000
Status: Rented

---

name: unit3
payment: 3000
Status: Available

---

output:

[text widget]
total rented: 3000

what is the custom code for the text widget so that i can display the sum?

i've tried to search for solution on youtube and fb but i can't find an exact solution